# how to execute spark program efficient in cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 node hadoop cluster. Each with 16GB RAM and 512GB Harddisk.

I have written spark program like below one

Code :

```
val input = sc.wholeTextFiles("folderpath/*")

do some operations on input.
convert it to dataframe. then register temptable. execute insert command to insert the dataframe value to hive table.
```

Then I open host 1 (which is my namenode of the cluster) terminal & I run spark submit command like

```
>spark-submit --class com.sample.parser --master yarn Parser.jar.
```

But it takes more than 50 mins to process 25 files which totals around 1gb.And when I check spark UI, executor list has only my host 2. host 1 is listed as driver.

So practically only one node is executing the program(host 2). Why?

Is there a way that I can have my driver also to execute the program. so that it runs little faster? Am I doing something wrong? Basically I want my driver node also to be part of executor(Both machines have 8 cores).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried `--num-executors 10`?

Comment: Yes. I did. But Still only my host 2 is executing. Not host 1. This is what I have tried.  "spark-submit --class com.sample.parser --master yarn Parser.jar.  --num-executors 16 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 16". But no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spark-submit` by default runs in client(local) mode, in order to submit spark job in cluster mode use `--deploy-mode` as:

```
spark-submit \
--class com.sample.parser \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
Parser.jar
```

> [--deploy-mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html): Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes
>   (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)

also, experiment with `--num-executors <n>` - with different `<n>` values...and see if it make any difference with perfomance of your app.

Comment: Yes. It was cluster mode I should have tried. It worked. Thank you.